# How to upgrade Zend_Loader from 1.7 to 1.8?

Tags: zend-framework, autoload, zend-autoloader, zend-loader, autoloader

I have been using this, and it works fine in 1.7, but not in 1.8.

```
    require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
    Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

It says it's deprecated, and that I should use Zend_Loader_Autoloader instead, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Got any in-progress code with the Autoloader yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a bare minimum you'll need to change the code to

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

If you have some code that is not namespaced, like models, you'll need this too:

```
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
```

More details at http://akrabat.com/2009/04/30/zend_loaders-autoloader_deprecated-in-zend-framework-18/